# Swift closure exception handling

Tags: swift, closures, swift4

I have a closure defined in this way:

```
 let processor: (MyBuffer) throws -> MyBuffer { buffer in

    let outputBuffer = try? self.processBuffer(self, inputBuffer: buffer)
    return outputBuffer

 }
```

`self.processBuffer()` throws an exception if it is not able to output a valid non nil buffer. But the Swift compiler complains about the return type as optional. My question is weather the only right way to deal with such a situation is to force unwrap the optional, or there is a better way to handle it?

Comment: throws -> MyBuffer?  and when u use it outside use guard let or if let

Answer (score 1):

Use `try` instead of `try?`.  If `processBuffer` throws, then the uncaught error will be thrown from your closure.  Otherwise, you'll have a valid `outputBuffer` to return.

```
let processor: (MyBuffer) throws -> MyBuffer = { buffer in

    let outputBuffer = try self.processBuffer(self, inputBuffer: buffer)
    return outputBuffer

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case the buffer could fail, and your return type says that always should return a buffer you 
can try to do a lot of things one of them changing the return type to be  `-> MyBuffer?` .

And when you use the `processor` you can use either `guard let` or `if let`

force unwrapping using `!` is risky as if at any point if the value was `nil` the app would crash

Read more about optional chaining in Swift documentation [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 0):

Force wrapping values might be dangerous, as it may lead to crashing of applications.

Do force wrap, when you sure shot (100%) know the optional will contain a value at any given time.

```
let processor: (MyBuffer) throws -> MyBuffer? { buffer in
     guard let outputBuffer = try? self.processBuffer(self, inputBuffer: buffer) else { return nil }
     return outputBuffer
}
```

To invoke the following you will make sure you are getting the `buffer` you need before using it.

```
guard let buffer = try? processor else { // no buffer was processed, hence you don't proceed the control flow.
    return
}
// you got processed buffer, hence use it.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throws the exception again or handle it.

If you want to handle it you have to wrap your code into do-catch, then :

```
 let processor: (MyBuffer) -> MyBuffer{ buffer in

 do{
   let outputBuffer = try self.processBuffer(self, inputBuffer: buffer)
   return outputBuffer
}catch HERE_THE_ERROR_TYPE{
 //HERE HOW TO HANDLE THE ERROR
}

}
```

Moreover, you if you want to throw the error:

```
 let processor: (MyBuffer) throws -> MyBuffer{ buffer in

let outputBuffer = try self.processBuffer(self, inputBuffer: buffer)

return output

 }
```

Then you can handle the error on closure call, or throw it again.

Now, note that if your function throws an error, you can handle it with optionals, just like you did. This mean that you have to handle or check the optional value ( guard-let, if-let or what you prefer). That's why if the function processBuffer throws an error, it will assign to outputBuffer a nil value, this mean that you don't need the throws declaration:

```
 let processor: (MyBuffer) -> MyBuffer?{ buffer in

let outputBuffer = try? self.processBuffer(self, inputBuffer: buffer)
//HERE YOU CAN CHECK IF OUTPUT_BUFFER IS NIL OR NOT
// Otherwise a nil value can be returned
return output

 }
```

For more info, check this documentation:
[Swift error handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html)